# Jquery How remove active classname of ul list a link event with ancestors closest

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

Y can't acces a list with each for remove classname active of my UL List

My HTML:

```
<ul ListMaster>
  <li><a>Link A</a></li>
  <li><a>Link B</a></li>
  <li><a class="active">Link C</a></li>
  <li><a>Link D</a></li>
  <li><a>Link E</a></li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on("click","ul[ListMaster] li a", function() { // Good Job

        var list = $(this).closest("ul[ListaFondo] li"); // Im not sure

            $(list).each(function(){
                $(this+" a").removeClass("active"); // here the problem
            });

            $(this).addClass("active"); // Good

    return false;
});
```

Simple CSS:

```
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
li{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.active{
  background-color: SteelBLue;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
```

Note: I need to access from the (a tag necessarily, without putting ID to UL or similar) because I have several UL lists.

My Code:

https://jsfiddle.net/r0b79uys/10/

Sorry guys, My english is poor .

Comment: Solution by @madalinivascu, Code updated with multiple UL List

https://jsfiddle.net/r0b79uys/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
$(document).on("click","ul[ListMaster] li a", function() {
            $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass("active"); // go back to the ul using closest find all active anchor classes and remove the class from them 
            $(this).addClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z1f47gnh/)

Comment: Thank very much @madalinivascu You solution code is working for multiple UL List. :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you have to remove the active class first on the list a element.

So ,

```
$(document).on("click","ul[ListMaster] li a", function() { // Good Job

    //var list = $(this).closest("ul[ListaFondo] li"); // i commented out this

        $("li a").removeClass("active"); // removed  this 

        $(this).addClass("active"); // Good

    return false;
});
```

And updated the fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/r0b79uys/10/
```

Comment: what happens if he has 2 list that use the active class?

Comment: as per question it is not specified that if it has multiple active class so operated on single

Comment: Thanks also for your help Sanjit Bhardwaj, as well as serving to realize that the selection ("li a") also  :)